# Switch windows in QT GUI app

Tags: c++, windows, qt, header, qt4

I am trying to make a link between my 3 windows , so I put this in my `mainwindow.h` :

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include "video.h"
#include "flightdata.h"

namespace Ui {
    class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

public slots:
   void openNewWindowVideo();
    void openNewWindowData();


private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
  video *myVideoWindow;
  flightdata *myDataWindow;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

And this in my implementation:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
   connect(ui->actionVideo,SIGNAL(triggered()),this,SLOT(openNewWindowVideo()));

  connect(ui->actionFlight_data,SIGNAL(triggered()),this,SLOT(openNewWindowData()));

}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::openNewWindowVideo()
{
  myVideoWindow = new video();
 myVideoWindow->show();
  this->close();

}

void MainWindow::openNewWindowData()
{
 myDataWindow = new flightdata();
 myDataWindow->show();
  this->close();

}
```

This works.

But when O follow the same steps for the 2 other windows ( `file.h` + `file.cpp` ),

iI get the error : 
    qt error: 'flightdata' does not name a type
    qt error: 'video' does not name a type

But when I include just first window and not the 2 others , I don't get this problem.

Maybe it is being caused by recursion.

Comment: do you include all the files you need everywhere ?

Comment: yeah the problem is that i have 3 file that i must include
and every time i must include 2 in each class 

but when i do this just for one class , it s working 10/10 
but when i make the includes in all the class it s turn to this error 

Bcs simply if i include X.h in Y.h , and in the some time i need to incule Y.h in X.h , qt will have problem to generate the file

Comment: forward declare your classes

Answer (score 1):

Don't include your other classes in header files. Include them in source files only.

If you for some reason need to use another class in a header of other class, use forward declaration instead of include.

Header:

```
// no include for 'video.h'
class video;

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow {
  //...
  video *myVideoWindow;
};
```

Source:

```
#include "video.h"
//...
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, there are potentially two things that may be wrong:

1. Pre-processor/MACRO

   If you created the other windows with QtCreator/Designer, the #ifndef macros should be  unique.  Meaning, video.h should have something like:

   ```
   #ifndef VIDEOWINDOW_H
   #define VIDEOWINDOW_H
   ```

   instead of the default

   ```
   #ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
   #define MAINWINDOW_H
   ```

   These #ifndef MACROS are intended to help include the contents of the header file once and only once.
2. Missing include paths

   Also, if you're using QtCreator, the editor should display #include "video.h" and #include "flightdata.h" as a link (control + left click).  If the syntax is underlined red, it means that the project can't find those files.

   Then you'll need to check to make sure that the files are either in your project folder or add have the path to those files added in the qmake variable INCLUDEPATH of your pro file.

   ```
   # e.g.
   INCLUDEPATH += ../myflightdata ../myvideofiles
   ```